Has anyone successfully converted a PyTorch-based LLM to ONNX Runtime to reduce file size?
I’m exploring the idea of converting PyTorch and TensorFlow models to ONNX Runtime to optimize performance and reduce file sizes. Since most large language models (LLMs) are built using PyTorch, I was wondering if anyone has successfully converted these models to ONNX Runtime?
If so, were there any noticeable reductions in file size or improvements in performance? Any guidance, experiences, or challenges encountered would be appreciated.
Here is what I have tried using kaggle notebook:
import os
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Check if GPU is available and use it
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Specify the model name
model_name = "mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3"

# Load the model and tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, use_auth_token=True)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, use_auth_token=True , device_map="auto")


# Create a dummy input tensor and move it to GPU
dummy_input = tokenizer("Hello, world!", return_tensors="pt")["input_ids"].to(device)


import gc
# Clean up memory before exporting
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()

# Export the model to ONNX format with full path and opset version 14
onnx_model_path = "/kaggle/working/mistral_7b.onnx"

torch.onnx.export(
    model,
    dummy_input,
    onnx_model_path,
    input_names=["input_ids"],
    output_names=["output"],
    dynamic_axes={"input_ids": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"}},
    opset_version=14
)

print(f"Model has been successfully converted to ONNX and saved at {onnx_model_path}")


I tried running models as ONNX as well as in GGUF which makes it possible to run them on CPU generally.
Standard practice for reducing size and memory requirements of (small) LLMs seems to be creating quantized versions of the models, e.g. https://huggingface.co/TheBloke/Llama-2-7B-GGUF
Not sure exactly what your question is though since you already seem to have implemented it yourself - or did it not work for you?

were you sucessfull when you tried running as onnx ?  because right now this procedure wasnt complete as my storage ran out on kaggle notebook.  so before running this code to any cloud provider , i would just need to know if this is possible. i mean that would be ground breaking , no? to make the LLM models have minimal file size so they can run on cpu
